# What is the difference between "MessageAttributeName.N" and "AttributeName.N" in SQS ReceiveMessage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The SQS "ReceiveMessage" endpoint has two params that seem to do the same thing and I don't understand the API docs. Can someone explain the difference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

```
AttributeName.N
A list of attributes that need to be returned along with each message
```

```
MessageAttributeName.N
The name of the message attribute, where N is the index.
...
When using ReceiveMessage, you can send a list of attribute names to receive, or you can return all of the attributes by specifying All
```

It seems that they both do the same thing, i.e. specifying which attributes should be returned on fetched messages.
Is there any difference? If not, which is preferred?

Answer (score 5):

I see now:

`AttributeName` returns AWS's attributes like "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp"

`MessageAttributeName` returns message (user specified) attributes